# Is static analysis really formal verification?

Tags: static-analysis, formal-verification, formal-semantics

I have been reading about formal verification and the basic point is that it requires a formal specification and model to work with. However, many sources classify static analysis as a formal verification technique, some mention abstract intepretation and mention its use in compilers.
So I am confused - how can these be formal verification if there is no formal description of the model?
EDIT: A source I found reads:

> Static analysis: the abstract semantics is computed automatically from
>   the program text according to predefined abstractions (that can
>   sometimes be tailored automatically/manually by the user)

So does it mean it works just on the source code with no need for formal specification? This would be what static analysers do.

Also, is static analysis possible without formal verification? E.g. does SonarQube really perform formal methods?

Comment: *"...many sources classify static analysis as a formal verification technique"* **Can you name/link few of these sources?...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of hardware and software systems, **formal verification is the act of proving or disproving the correctness of intended algorithms** underlying a system with respect to a certain formal specification or property, using formal methods of mathematics.

> How can these be formal verification if there is no formal description of the model?

A static analyser will generate control/data flow of a piece of code, upon which [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis#Formal_methods) can then be applied to verify conformance to the system's/unit's expected design model.

*Note that **modelling/formal-specification** is NOT a part of **static-analysis**.

However combined together, both of these tools are useful in formal verification.*

---

For example if a system is modeled as a Finite State Machine (FSM) with

- **a pre-defined number of states**
  *defined by a combination of specific values of certain member data.*
- **a pre-defined set of transitions between various states**
  *defined by the list of member functions.*

> Then the results of static analysis will help in **formal verification** of the fact that
>   the control NEVER flows along a path that is NOT present in the above FSM model.

Also, if a model can be simply defined in terms of type-definition, data-flow, control-flow/call-graph, i.e. code-metrics that a static-analyser can verify, then static-analysis itself is sufficient to formally verify that code conforms to such a model.
[image: Static Analysis and Formal Verification]

<sub>*NOTE1. The yellow region above would be static analysers used to enforce stuff like coding-guidelines and naming-conventions i.e. aspects of code that cannot affect the program's behavior.*</sub>

<sub>*NOTE2. The red region above would be formal verification that requires additional steps like 100% dynamic code-coverage, elimination of unused and dead code. These cannot be detected/enforced using a static-analyser.*</sub>

---

**Static analysis is highly effective in verifying that a system/unit is implemented using a subset of the language specification to meet goals laid out in the system/unit design.**

For example, if it is a design goal to prevent the stack memory from exceeding a particular limit, then one could apply a limit on the depth of recursion (or forbid recursive functions calls altogether). Static-analysis is used to identify such violations of design goals.

> In the absence of any warnings from the static-analyser,
>   the system/unit code stands formally verified against such design-goals of its respective model.

eg. [MISRA-C standard for Automotive software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C#Rules) defines a subset of C for use in automotive systems.

MISRA-C:2012 contains

- **143 rules** - each of which is checkable using static program analysis.
- **16 "directives"** more open to interpretation, or relate to process.

Comment: Thank you, so e.g. SonarQube use formal methods? Because I have never read something like that

Comment: @user970696 I couldn't find any documentation that SonarQube uses formal-methods. However, a similar tool [**Goanna** makes an explicit claim about using formal methods alongwith its static-analyser](http://redlizards.com/products/technology/).

Comment: @TheCodeArist The thing is, does Sonar do static analysis if it does not use formal methods? I found it confusing as the meaning is not clear.

Comment: Yes. Sonar does static analysis. If you also need your software to be formally verified, then you would need to perform additional steps like defining a model and using formal methods to verify the code sticks to the model. You can use the results of SonarQube's static analysis as an input to your formal verification methods. Also if the model can be simply defined in terms of control-flow/call-graph, then static-analysis itself is sufficient to formally verify the model.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is confusing as some books or articles say that "static analysis" is a formal method. If I am not mistaken, Sonar can detect also some "design" errors and that would not fit in the pure static analysis.

Comment: @user970696 these books would be referring to the orange area of intersection in the diagram above. Certain aspects of static analysis help in formal verification. But static-analyis is NOT just about formal-verification and formal-verification isn't simply about static analysis. Hopefully the venn diagram clarifies this very concisely.

Comment: Static analysis is as hard as formal verification.  For example, in contexts where self-modifying code or unreachable code is present, a static analyzer would proceed incorrectly if not being able to precisely determine post-conditions and the like.  So static analyzers which do not make use of formal methods can only handle a subset of all theoretically possible scenarios.  So the part of the Venn diagram where static analysis does not overlap with formal verification is really only for a subset of all possible programs where certain assumptions hold.

Answer (score 1):

Static analysis just means "read the source code and possibly complain". (Contrast to "dynamic analysis", meaning, "run the program and possibly complain about some execution behavior").

There are lots of different types of possible static-analysis complaints.
One possible complaint might be,

```
 Your source code does not provably satisfy a formal specification
```

This complaint would be based on formal verification if the static analyzer had a formal specification which it interpreted "formally", a formal interpretation of the source code, and a trusted theorem prover that could not find an appropriate theorem.

All the other kinds of complaints you might get from a static analyzer are pretty much heuristic opinions, that is, they are based on some informal interpretation of the code (or specification if it indeed even exists).

The "heavy duty" static analyzers such as Coverity etc. have pretty good program models, but they don't tell you that your code meets a specification (they don't even look to see if you have one).  At best they only tell you that your code does something undefined according to the language ("dereference a null pointer") and even that complaint isn't always right.

So-called "style checkers" such as MISRA are also static analyzers, but their complaints are essentially "You used a construct that some committee decided was bad form".  That's not actually a bug, it is pure opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly classify static analysis as a kind of formal verification.

> how can these be formal verification if there is no formal description of the model?

For static analysis tools, the model is implicit (or in some tools, partly implicit). For example, "a well-formed C++ program will not leak memory, and will not access memory that hasn't been initialized". These sorts of rules can be derived from the language specification, or from the coding standards of a particular project.

Comment: Thanks. But is every static analysis also formal verification? I am under the impression that also tools dealing with syntax and coding conventions are called static analysis tools. SonarQube is something I am not sure about